# julia: version `LLVM_3.8' not found (required by /usr/bin/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/julia/libjulia.so)

Tags: linux, debian, llvm, julia

I tried to install julia with the package manager of my linux distribution (a Debian testing, i.e currently Debian Stretch).

After runing :

```
sudo apt install julia llvm-3.8 llvm-3.8-dev
```

I run the `julia` interpreter:

```
julia
```

And I got this return:

```
julia: /usr/bin/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libLLVM-3.8.so.1: version `LLVM_3.8' not found 
(required by /usr/bin/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/julia/libjulia.so)
```

I have already tried to do:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/llvm-3.8/lib/libLLVM-3.8.so.1 /usr/bin/llvm-link-3.8 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

But it doesn't work.
Do you have some ideas?

Thanks

Comment: find the `libjulia.so` file used (e.g. using `locate`) and check what the output of `ldd /path/to/libjulia.so` is. Might give you useful feedback (or not)

Comment: Also, why not just install from the website directly. It's more likely to be an up-to-date version, plus all dynamic libraries seem to be included.

Comment: I recommend you compile from source or download the generic linux binaries, as Tasos mentioned.